# When is it ever appropriate to place Javascript inside the body of a document?

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

The client has a bunch of Javascript that calls Microsoft Ajax etc. Aside from web page analytics which make sense to load at the same time static resources are loaded, wouldn't it make sense to load any AJAX scripts in the head instead of the body?

Ultimately the result is a bloated load time for the page since all the Javascript is being loaded at time of render.

What is your ideal placement of certain Javascript in a web page?

Comment: All JavaScript resources are loaded immediately as soon as the parser encounters them in the HTML source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Placing Javascript at the *end* of the body can help with the perception of good page load speed. Scripts in the head block other activity while they're run.

The claim of "bloated load time" is actually backwards.  Putting the scripts in the `<head>` means that the page won't be parsed and none of it will be rendered until all the scripts are loaded and executed. (Well, all the directly-loaded scripts.)

Comment: Thanks for the correction however are you saying there is no reason whatsoever to put JS in the head? I'm thinking if you wanted to load an event listener first before allowing the user to access any UI would be a good example.

Comment: No, I would not say that there is **no** reason to put JS in the `<head>`.  For example, there may be in-page snippets of code that rely on some utility library, so sometimes code really has to come first.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to put your scripts at the bottom of the document. Yahoo covers it on their [Best Practices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).

Answer (score 0):

you can place javascript anywhere you like.

you usually wanna put external JS in the header section.

Other than that. you can put them anywhere.

Comment: You do not usually want to put external JS in the header section. You usually want to put it at the bottom of the page, so that the page will render faster for the user.